# ar.js different aspect ration of meshes in Desktop and Mobile

Tags: javascript, three.js, ar.js

I have a little problem. There are my desktop version:
[image]
And there is my mobile version:
[image]
You can see there is different aspect ration...
How I can set the same aspect ration on Mobile (as on Desktop version).

```
// create atToolkitContext
var arToolkitContext = new THREEx.ArToolkitContext({
    cameraParametersUrl: THREEx.ArToolkitContext.baseURL + 'patterns/camera_para.dat',
    detectionMode: 'mono',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the:

```
// resolution of at which we detect pose in the source image
canvasWidth: 640,
canvasHeight: 480,
```

to match your expected mobile canvas?

Comment: I set: window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight and application doesn't find marker...